# Cloud Firestore connection is slow on some devices

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Any ideeas why Cloud Firestore connection is slow for my client yet for me is almost instant? The Firebase server selected is europe-west3, my client is in UK and I am in Romania.

He has a relative good download speed, according to speedtest.net, but downloading data from Cloud Firestore is extremely slow. Even 6 documents, with a total of 8 small fields, are loading extremely slow.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @VadimPopov this is the code for getting those 6 documents I mentioned: collection.orderBy("dateAdded", descending: true).snapshots(); 

A listener which gets all data from a collection;

Comment: Try updating google and firebase related packages

Comment: @PavelShastov will try that as soon I will be able.

Comment: @adi Did you manage to figure out why this happened?

Comment: @Bracher in my case it was browser specific issue. 

At the time I asked the question the issue was with Chrome and using other browsers (Firefox and Edge) worked without issues. 

Deleting cache or resetting the browser didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the browser.

On the same machine, but different browser there weren't any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Firebase Blog Post ["Why is my Cloud Firestore query slow?"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/08/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow.html)

I think you should use implement [Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on your data.

Firebase provides powerful tools for [ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and [querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) your data. Specifically, Firebase allows you to do ad-hoc queries on a collection of nodes using any common child key.

> A node's key is indexed automatically, so there is no need to index it
> explicitly.

Comment: I think Firebase already takes care of indexing all documents by all fields, hence the limitations it imposes when it comes to compound indexes

Comment: the documentation you have linked refers to Realtime Database, an entirely different product

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it isn't what I need.
1. You are mainly pointing to Realtime Database, which is different like ppicom mentioned.
2. I have looked at "Why is my Cloud Firestore query slow" but the issue is the same for both big and small data. For example it takes a long time to get the user info from the database which is a document with: name, email, phone number, uid and category id.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might be the reason, but I think it is a great idea to make sure it is initilizing firebase before querying and logging errors.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}
```

Initialize before operations:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Put above code and operations on try, catch, log and see what happens when it is slow, it might be initializing in the wrong time or not initializing and taking extra time to operate.